# Anylogic set agent's parameter or variable values across flowchat

Tags: variables, parameters, anylogic, agent

In an Anylogic model, I'm trying to modify agent's parameters and variables for example on exit of a queue. I've created a variable named "vaPe" of type "double" in the "Ari" agent, and inserted the following code in the "On exit" action type of a queue: "Agent.vaPe=1;". However, I get the following error "vaPe cannot be resolved or is not a field". How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

First, Java is a case-sensitive language so you should write `agent.vaPe = 1;`, with small caps.

Second, check in your Queue under Advanced -> Agent type, which agent type this block expects, it should be set to Ari. (Generally you should set it in the first block of your process flow, then all the following connected blocks will copy the setting automatically.)

Comment: Thanks very ,much for your answer mczandrea. I've entered the command for the assignment in the source block, in which "Entity Type" field appears "Agent". Thats why I wrote "Agent.vaPe = 1;"  instead of "agent.vaPe = 1;". If I input "agent.vaPe = 1;", the error chages to "Agent cannot be resolved to a variable".  As to the Advanced -> Agent type, it is already set as "Ari".  I would appreciate any further suggestions as to the possible causes of the problem, which persists.

Comment: Where are you writing it in your Source block? Calling `agent` only works if the little lightbulb lists it as a keyword. See this blog post if you don't know what I mean: https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling